# Snakemake: catch output file whose name cannot be changed

Tags: snakemake

As part of a Snakemake pipeline that I'm building, I have to use a program that does not allow me to specify the file path or name of an output file.

E.g. when running the program in the working directory `workdir/` it produces the following output:
`workdir/output.txt`

My snakemake rule looks something like this:

```
rule NAME:
    input: "path/to/inputfile"
    output: "path/to/outputfile"
    shell: "somecommand {input} {output}"
```

So every time the rule NAME runs, I get an additional file `output.txt` in the snakemake working directory, which is then overwritten if the rule NAME runs multiple times or in parallel.

I'm aware of shadow rules, and adding `shadow: "full"` allows me to simply ignore the `output.txt` file. However, I'd like to keep `output.txt` and save it in the same directory as the `outputfile`. Is there a way of achieving this, either with the shadow directive or otherwise?

I was also thinking I could prepend `somecommand` with a `cd` command, but then I'd probably run into other issues downstream when linking up other rules to the outputs of the rule `NAME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply moving it directly afterwards in the shell part (provided `somecommand` completes successfully)?

```
rule NAME:
    input: "path/to/inputfile"
    output: "path/to/outputfile"
    params: 
        output_dir = "path/to/output_dir",
    shell: "somecommand {input} {output} && mv output.txt {params.output_dir}/output.txt"
```

EDIT: for multiple executions of NAME in parallel, combining with `shadow: "full"` could work:

```
rule NAME:
    input: "path/to/inputfile"
    output:
        output_file = "path/to/outputfile"
        output_txt = "path/to/output_dir/output.txt"
    shadow: "full"
    shell: "somecommand {input} {output.output_file} && mv output.txt {output.output_txt}"
```

That should run each execution of the rule in its own temporary dir, and by specifying the moved output.txt as an output Snakemake should move it to the real output dir once the rule is done running.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This would work, but only if there are no jobs of rule `NAME` running in parallel. Otherwise it wouldn't be clear to which job the `output.txt` file belongs.

Comment: @D-Cru good catch, tweaked it now - I think you were on the right track with `shadow`, documentation says one use case is to "simplify your workflow by not having to worry about unique filenames for all outputs of all rules" and it does keep any files specified as output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kat Steinke. I've tested your suggestion and it seems to work perfectly for this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I was also thinking I could prepend `somecommand` with a `cd` command, but then I'd probably run into other issues downstream when linking up other rules to the outputs of the rule `NAME`.

I think you are on the right track here. Each `shell` block is run in a separate process with the working directory inherited from the snakemake process (specified with the `--directory` argument on the command line). Accordingly, `cd` commands in one `shell` block will not affect other jobs from the same rule or other downstream/upstream jobs.

```
rule NAME:
    input: "path/to/inputfile"
    output: "path/to/outputfile"
    shell: 
        """
        input_file=$(realpath "{input}")  # get the absolute path, before the `cd`
        base_dir=$(dirname "{output}")
        cd "$base_dir"
        somecommand ...
        """
```

Comment: Thanks - this works well! One might get rather long shell commands if there are many different inputs/outputs, but it avoids the use of shadow. It does not work properly when running multiple instances of rule `NAME` in parallel within the same output folder. But for this case, different output folders could easily be specified via a wildcard.